# Scheme: Lists of three dotted elements returning strangely (like an infix operator?)

Tags: list, syntax, scheme, racket, infix-notation

I am a new Scheme/Racket student, so please excuse any blatant syntax errors.

It came up in class today that the scheme list `'(a, b, c)` should be invalid, but when we ran it, it returned:

```
>'(a . b . c)  
(b a c)
```

Which makes no sense. Afaik, the interpreter should create a cons cell with car 'a and cdr 'b, and the 'c should be invalid. That said, the interpreter is doing something really strange here. This works with #lang scheme, #lang racket, and others. We are using DrRacket as the interpreter.

Interestingly,

```
>'(a . b . c . d)
```

throws an exception and dies.

I am very curious and would love to be able to understand this since I am new to the language. Google was very unhelpful (probably since the search terms are kind of ambiguous) Thank you!

EDIT:
It might be because `'(a . b . c)` is interpreted with b as an infix operator. For example: `>(4 . + . 6)` returns 10. Perhaps the interpreter is using b like an operator? i.e. `(b a c)` like `(+ 4 6)`, infix-wise.

Expermentation says:

```
>(define b +)  
>(define a 4)  
>(define c 6)  
>(a . b . c)  
10
```

So I think this solves the problem, but I still don't fully understand the use of the "." operator in this case. I think we've solved this, but any more insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The dots on either side of the operator remind me of Fortran: 1 .LT. 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: you got it.  For more information on this Racket-specific use of dots, see the documentation for [infix](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=infix#%28idx._%28gentag._165._%28lib._scribblings/reference/reference..scrbl%29%29%29)  in the Racket docs.

Answer (score 4):

It's a special feature of Racket's reader. (See John's answer.)

For other implementations, you can instead use the [readable S-expressions](http://www.dwheeler.com/readable/) reader to be able to read infix expressions. It uses curly braces. e.g., `{3 + 4}` is read in as `(+ 3 4)`. Even more special (than Racket's infix reader), you can use `{3 + 4 + 5}` or `{3 + 4 + 5 + 6}`; they will read as `(+ 3 4 5)` and `(+ 3 4 5 6)` respectively.

Comment: See also this implementation of readable S-exps for Racket: http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=sweet.plt&owner=asumu